# String Game, creating a specific Loop? c++

Tags: c++, file-io

Im new to programming and C++ and I started making a little string type game for fun, which gives the user two options through out the program, but in the final part of the program i cant get it to output a unique option for the final input(makeCure) - which i only want to output at the end not through out the program. Hope Im making sense :/ .Iv tried and tried and tried and the more i try the more probloms I create. Iv shown below in my code where Im sure the problom lies. Any advice would much appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string;

bool intro(void);
void room(bool enemy, bool data, bool cure, string description);

//player stats
string Name = "";

//enemy states
string enemyName = "";

//data stats
string dataName = "";

//Cure - Option in room7 only
string makeCure = "";

//room descriptions(string constructs)

const string room1 = "You enter the first town of infected Zombies.";
const string room2 = "You are overwelmed by Zombies, and plunder into the sewers to escape.";
const string room3 = "You make your way to safety and find yourself in the Central Town Hall.";
const string room4 = "You decide to venture into the local forest to find the finalingrediants";
const string room5 = "You venture further for the final ingrediant, into a nearby Cave.";
const string room6 = "Its time for you to face the Zombie General!!!";
const string room7 = "You work day and Night in the Labs to make the Cure.";


int main(void)
{
    if(intro())
        return 0;
    dataName = "First Ingrediant- Zombie Rags with infected DNA";
    enemyName = "Zombie Soldior";
    room(true, true, false, room1);

    enemyName = "Massive Zombie Rat";
    room(true, false, false, room2);

    dataName = "Seconed Ingrediant- StemCells";
    enemyName = "Mutated Scientists";
    room(true, true, false, room3);

    dataName = "Third Magic-Mushrooms";
    room(false, true, false, room4);

    dataName = "Fourth Final Ingrediant - Coffee Beans";
    enemyName = "Commander Zombie";
    room(true, true, false, room5);

    enemyName = "Zombie General";
    room(false, true, false, room6);
    return 0;


    makeCure = "Elixier to Save the World";
    room(false, false, true, room7);
    return 0;
}

bool intro(void)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;

    cout << "Brave Soul!!! What is your name?\n";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Ahh... " << Name << " You say.." << "How about Zombie Slayer?.. Good, glad we agree!\n";

    cout << "Humanity is in need of your Help, "
        << "The world is being infected by the\n"
        << "ZD1678 ZOMBIE VIRUS \n"
        << "And we need to send you to Cape Town to stop the central spread.\n"
        << "Your task will be tough, but we know you can do it \n"
        << "Will you accept the challenge?\n\n";

    cout << "1)Yes. \n"
        << "2)No. \n\n";
    int response;
    cin >> response;
    return !(response ==1);
}

void room(bool enemy, bool data, bool cure, string description)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std:: cin;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << description.c_str() << "\n\n";
        int response = 0;
        do
        {
            cout << "Shall Our Hero continue his Quest?\n";
            if(enemy)
                cout << "1) Attack the "             
                << enemyName.c_str() << "\n";
            else if(!enemy)
                cout << "1) venture further...."; 

            if(data)
                cout << "2)Pick up the "    
                << dataName.c_str() << "\n";
            cin >> response;

            /* Trying to create the last if that only kicks in at room7( string makeCure )
            * that displays the option to make the cure
            * This is where my Problem is.
            * Iv tried anouther if
            * and else
            * and while and nothing works, its just messes up everything..
            * badly
            */

        } while(response < 1 || response > 2);

        switch(response)
        {
        case 1:
            if(enemy)
            {
                enemy = !enemy;
                cout << "You slay the deadly "
                    << enemyName.c_str() << "\n";
            }
            else if(!enemy)
                return;
            break;
        case 2:
            data = !data;
            cout << "You pick up the "
                <<  dataName.c_str() << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use `c_str()` to print things.

Comment: ai Is using c_str() here wrong or bad practice? if so I'll have to have a word with mt teacher.

Comment: There's just no reason to. You can print strings directly without having to convert them to C strings first, so why bother? The one time you might is if you store null characters in the string and only want to print to the first null.

Comment: Please make the question clear. From my understanding i think what you need is code block like this if(cure){}

Comment: @555k and fix the switch. I believe the OP only got lost in the if/else/if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you probably want to do is dynamically generate a list of possible events each time you write out the list and present it to the user, then you can match the response to the list to get what the user wants to do.  like this:

```
enum EventType
{
    ET_Enemy,
    ET_Item,
    ET_Cure,
    ET_Continue,
    ET_MAX
};

void room(bool enemy, bool data, bool cure, string description)
{
 using std::cout;
 using std:: cin;

    int currentEventChoices[ET_MAX];
    int numEventChoices;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << description.c_str() << "\n\n";


        int response = 0;
        do
        {
            numEventChoices = 0;

            cout << "Shall Our Hero continue his Quest?\n";

            if(enemy)
            {
                cout << (numEventChoices+1) << ") Attack the "             
                        << enemyName.c_str() << "\n";
                currentEventChoices[numEventChoices] = ET_Enemy;
                numEventChoices++;
            }
            if(data)
            {
                 cout << (numEventChoices+1) << ") Pick up the "    
                        << dataName.c_str() << "\n";
                currentEventChoices[numEventChoices] = ET_Item;
                numEventChoices++;
            }
            if(cure)
            {
                cout << (numEventChoices+1) << ") cure related string "
                        << makeCure.c_str() << "\n";
                currentEventChoices[numEventChoices] = ET_Cure;
                numEventChoices++;
            }

            cout << (numEventChoices+1) << ") venture further....\n"; // note if this is only meant to be an option if there is no enemy, put it in an else after the if(enemy)
            numEventChoices++;

                cin >> response;



        } while(response < 1 || response > numEventChoices);

        switch(currentEventChoices[response-1])
        {


            case ET_Enemy:
                enemy = !enemy;
                    cout << "You slay the deadly "
                            << enemyName.c_str() << "\n";
                break;
            case ET_Item:
                 data = !data;
                cout << "You pick up the "
                        <<  dataName.c_str() << "\n";
                break;
            case ET_Cure:
                //do cure stuff
                break;
            case ET_Continue:
                return;
        }
   }
}
```

the trouble you are having is that by just using a very static next of if/else statements each time you want to match the option number to the event, it gets very complex and messy, it was fine when there was just the 4 cases of there being an enemy or not, or data or not. but now you are adding another branch with cure, its just got really complex to do it that way.

Comment: Yeah very messy.But your solution is GREAT. Thank you Matt, think im going to have to learn a little more before I try your way, but I will.

Comment: @CodingIsFun yeah it was kinda hard to explain, if you have any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you need, so tell me if it's not what you wanted.

Using braces and indenting consistently can really help with this:

```
do {
    cout << "Shall Our Hero continue his Quest?\n"; 
    if (enemy) {
        cout << "1) Attack the " << enemyName << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "1) venture further...."; 
    }
    if (data) {
        cout << "2) Pick up the " << dataName << "\n";
    }
    if (cure) {
        cout << "2) take the " << makeCure << "\n";
    }
    cin >> response;
} while (response < 1 || response > 2);
```

and fix "case 2" in the switch part:

```
 case 2:
        if (data) {
            data = false;
            cout << "You pick up the " <<  dataName << "\n";
        } else if (cure) {
            // fill in ...
        }
        break;
```

Notes:

1. You can use `endl` (from `std`) instead of '\n'. `cout << "hello" << endl;`
2. You can pass many of your global variables as arguments, so you won't need them to be global (global is bad, in general).
3. Much of your game can be be squeeszed into arrays and structs - being "data driven" and "table driven". I don't know if you got there already, but you can try and identify these parts.
4. `if(enemy) ... else if(!enemy)` you don't need the `!enemy` part. it is implied by the `else`.

Comment: Thank you heaps Elazar! This helps alot, going to rewrite the program now to make it more practical.